Overriding @objc method from superclass
I want to override an @objc method in my derived class. The method declaration is the exact same as in the superclass:
class Test: DGCharts.LineChartView {
    @objc private func doubleTapGestureRecognized(_ recognizer: NSUITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
    }
}

This fails, obviously:

Method 'doubleTapGestureRecognized' with Objective-C selector
'doubleTapGestureRecognized:' conflicts with method
'doubleTapGestureRecognized' from superclass 'BarLineChartViewBase'
with the same Objective-C selector

But if I add override:
class Test: DGCharts.LineChartView {
    @objc override private func doubleTapGestureRecognized(_ recognizer: NSUITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
    }
}

Then it does not work either:

Method does not override any method from its superclass

Why? Is there an issue with the method being private, or that it is @objc, or ...?

Yes, being private is the problem. Why are you trying to override private stuff?

@Sweeper Some methods are buggy and/or functionality is missing, and I want to avoid forking the library.

Since it's ObjC, you could swizzle the methods, but I highly recommend against it, or trying to use overrides to fix bugs (it fundamentally fights the encapsulation of OOP by relying on internal details of the superclass). This looks like an open source library; send a PR. But the technical solution is "swizzle."

The private access control prevents you from overriding the method. There is also a doubleTapGestureRecognized version in DGCharts, specifically in BarLineChartViewBase.
You can make a quick example to see how it work:
class Bar {
    @objc private func foo() { }
}

class Bar2: Bar {
    @objc func foo() { } //an error occurs here

    @objc override func foo() { } //an error occurs here
}

And then try to remove private:
class Bar {
    @obj func foo() { }
}

class Bar2: Bar {
    @objc override func foo() { } //OK
}

The difference in this scenario with @objc is that, if both sub-class and parent-class have the same method, it will cause conflict. It works fine without @objc:
class Bar {
    private func foo() { }
}

class Bar2: Bar {
    func foo() { } //OK
}

So, since the doubleTapGestureRecognized private method was inside the framework, you cannot override it, it must be open.
